# Perl regex nested grouping results

Tags: regex, perl

I have files like this:

```
mu  (micro) | 10^(-6) | millionth
m  (milli) | 0.001 | thousandth
k  (kilo) | 10^3 | thousand
M  (mega) | 10^6 | million
```

And I would like to to produce files like:

```
| $mu  (micro)$ | $10^(-6)$ | $millionth$ |
| $m  (milli)$ | $0.001$ | $thousandth$ |
| $k  (kilo)$ | $10^3$ | $thousand$ |
| $M  (mega)$ | $10^6$ | $million$ |
```

I'm trying to use the perl regex. And so far the best reexpression I could come up with is:

```
perl -lpe '(([[:alnum:][:punct:]\s]+)\s+|\|\s*([[:alnum:][:punct:]\s]+)\s*\||\s*([[:alnum:][:punct:]\s]+))'
```

I know it's got a few of redundant `\s+`, but I tried removing them the result was worse. Current it only separates it in two part:

```
mu  (micro) | 10^(-6) | 
millionth
```

So how can I improve upon this, to get the desired result? I know I can use `s/foo/bar/g` to replace it but I can't get the expression to separate properly. Also how will I access the nested groups?

Perhaps there is a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: `perl -lpe '(([[:alnum:][:punct:]\s]+)\s+|\|\s*([[:alnum:][:punct:]\s]+)\s*\||\s*([[:alnum:][:punct:]\s]+))'` is nonsense. That's not valid Perl code.

Comment: If you know that the pipes are unique as separators: `perl -E '$s="mu  (micro) | 10^(-6) | millionth"; @a=split /\|/,$s; say "| \$" . (join "\$ | \$",@a) . "\$ |"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lpe '$_ = "| " . join(" | ", map "\$$_\$", split / \| /) . " |"'
```

In words: Split each line into fields (on `|`), wrap each field in `$...$`, join the fields with `|`, and add a `|` at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(\S+ +\S+) +\| +(\S+) +\| +(\S+)$/| \$$1\$ | \$$2\$ | \$$3\$ |/g'
```